# What is the minimum order of a 3-regular graph H containing G as an induced subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory

What is the minimum order of a 3-regular graph H containing the graph G(in diagram) as an induced subgraph?

[image: Graph G]

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asked for the given graph to be an *induced* subgraph, the degree-$3$ vertex of $G$ cannot be in a triangle. All vertices of the triangular prism lie in triangles, so $G$ cannot be induced in there; it is also easy to show that the other non-isomorphic graph on $6$ vertices, $K_{3,3}$, does not have $G$ induced.

The minimum number of vertices in $H$ is therefore $8$:
[image]

Comment: I get that since 3 is odd number of vertices 'n' must be even, but I did not understand how you concluded that it doesn't work for '6' and arrived at a solution with 8 vertices

Comment: @Krishan [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicGraph.html) conveniently shows cubic graphs with orders $4,6,8$. For showing that $K_{3,3}$ has no $G$ induced, note that every $4$-vertex path in $K_{3,3}$ can be closed into a cycle, but $G$ has a $4$-vertex path.

Comment: so did you use a hit and trial method to check for the first viable even no, which is 6, then for 8 and so on..

Comment: @Krishan Yes, and here it is clearly more than enough.